# Strange ELF binary

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, elf

I have a strange ELF binary. I can run this binary in 32bit linux.

But if I open this binary with IDA disassembler, IDA says "invalid entry point".

Result of readelf is as below:

```
root@meltdown-VirtualBox:/home/meltdown# readelf -S -l SimpleVM 

There are no sections in this file.

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0xc023dc
There are 2 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00c01000 0x00c01000 0x013c7 0x013c7 RWE 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00019c 0x0804b19c 0x0804b19c 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x1000
```

There is no section. I thought this binary is packed. But, last virtual address of first LOAD segment is 0xc023c7. And virtual address of entry point is 0xc023dc which is out of range...

Can someone tell me whats going on?

Thank you in advance.

- /proc/PID/maps is as follows (two processes are created...)

  ```
  root@meltdown-VirtualBox:/proc/3510# cat maps
  00110000-00111000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  006c0000-006c1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
  007d2000-007d4000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  00c01000-00c02000 rwxp 00000000 08:01 3801242    /home/meltdown/SimpleVM
  00ca4000-00e43000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17171359   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
  00e43000-00e45000 r-xp 0019f000 08:01 17171359   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
  00e45000-00e46000 rwxp 001a1000 08:01 17171359   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
  00e46000-00e49000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
  0804b000-0804c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  b77a7000-b77c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17171339   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
  b77c7000-b77c8000 r-xp 0001f000 08:01 17171339   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
  b77c8000-b77c9000 rwxp 00020000 08:01 17171339   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
  bfa90000-bfab1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]

  root@meltdown-VirtualBox:/proc/3511# cat maps
  00110000-00111000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  006c0000-006c1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
  007d2000-007d4000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  00c01000-00c02000 rwxp 00000000 08:01 3801242    /home/meltdown/SimpleVM
  00ca4000-00e43000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17171359   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
  00e43000-00e45000 r-xp 0019f000 08:01 17171359   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
  00e45000-00e46000 rwxp 001a1000 08:01 17171359   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
  00e46000-00e49000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
  0804b000-0804c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
  b77a7000-b77c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 17171339   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
  b77c7000-b77c8000 r-xp 0001f000 08:01 17171339   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
  b77c8000-b77c9000 rwxp 00020000 08:01 17171339   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
  bfa90000-bfab1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
  ```

Comment: (+1) Interesting question. However, I think we'd stand a higher chance of success if we could examine the actual binary.

Comment: What do `file SimpleVM` and `ldd SimpleVM` say?

Comment: I suspect, if this is a proprietary program, then its author wants to prevent it from disassembling. As it's known, the kernel is somewhat more permissive about the binary format (it happily accepts some slightly malformed executables that disassemblers/debuggers don't), and this fact is exploited in order to prevent a binary from being reverse engineered.

Comment: Could be that the file format is not compatible with the readelf executable used.  It would be interesting to see what shows up in the /proc/[PID]/maps file while it is running, or to debug it.

Comment: when I run SimpleVM, it prints "Input :" and waits for keyboard input. when I type something and press enter, it prints out "Wrong". and terminates.

Comment: ldd SimpleVM tells me this is not a dynamically linked binary

Comment: It's clear that the program modifies its mappings after it starts (including, apparently, unmapping the page containing the entry point), you should try and get a listing of the maps before it starts executing. In this case, run `gdb` on the binary and do `break *0xc023dc`, then `run`, then `info proc mappings`.

Comment: if I type b *0xc023dc, gdb tells me 'invalid memory address'.  I've analyzed this binary and it turns out it has false program header information(in purpose). the first LOAD segment size is smaller than actual LOAD segment size in file.  the reason it could run is because of the granularity of memory mapping as you answered.  I am still analyzing this binary but it is clear that this is some kind of polymorphic program which it writes it's own code during run time. anyway, your first answer turns out right. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because of the granularity of mapping length. The length of the mapping is going to be rounded up to be a multiple of the page size. On my system the page size is 4k so the mapping would be rounded up to 4k and encompass the entry point. Even with a page size of 1k the length would round up to 0x1400, enough to include the entry point. If the file is long enough then the extra bytes would probably come from the file instead of the page initialization.

Comment: Ok, it might not page fault *immediately* as a result of that.  But wouldn't the entry point be filled with whatever empty pages get filled with on that system?  If that's effectively a *nop* it would execute those until running off the end of the page; but the instruction could really be anything...

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've assumed that the file is big enough for the extended length. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: That might indeed be plausible, particularly if someone were trying to be sneaky and relying on behavior of a particular program loader.  It would be interesting to see what the file size "should be" based on the ELF header, vs. what it is.